# A GRE verbal question -- I think the given answer is wrong

Tags: verbs, gre

According to my understanding the choices to this question is only **A**. But the answer sheet says the correct choices are **A** and **C**. The question asks the conceptualization about *gender* in western culture.

In choice **C** it says:

> The idea of male/female binary gender is **not** generally considered the **norm** of contemporary Western civilization.

I don't know if I understand the word "norm" here correctly. If I understand it correctly, and the choice **C** is correct, I think it means *in general western consider a third gender in their culture*.

And the explanation to choice **C** even confuse me. It feels to me that the explanation contradict with choice.

I think this passage is quite simple, and maybe I misunderstand some key words. So please help me.

[image: Question]
[image: Answer]

Comment: There are two possibilities. 1: "Male/Female binary gender" means those who are neither male nor female. 2. There could be a mistake on the author's side. Remember "Male/Female gender binary" is what you have at the beginning and is not the same as the one in C.

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me – the answer key seems to describe the opposite of what choice C actually states.

Comment: Actually A and B are correct, and if you replace "C" with "B" in the explanation it all makes sense.

Comment: @Jim To not have the equivalent of *hijra* does not necessarily mean Western civilization does not believe in its concept. It's implied, perhaps, but it is not explicitly said.

Comment: The "not" in C shouldn't be there. An error which can cost candidates dearly on the day of the exam. The publishers ought to be informed, if they haven't been already.

Comment: I am using McGraw-Hill's GRE 2013 Edition. The latest is 2014. Hope they have fixed this issue. :)

Comment: It seems from the text that the polarity suggested by the *hijra* is female. So there is still a binary gender identity (male/female—count 'em). For it to move beyond binary, there would have to be a third sex that did not identify as male or female.

Comment: @Mari-LouA- From the text: *There is no equivalent of hijras in the contemporary Western conceptualization of gender*.  I take this to mean that not only do we not have a word for it, we don't even have the concept.

Comment: @ Jim : Hijra is known as "Eunuch" or "hermaphrodite" in English.. Refer to this link from wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijra_(South_Asia)

Comment: @Noah's point about the different word order is significant, because it does change the meaning. Was this intentional? Some textual matter here appears sloppy, but some I find  intentionally vague to make it more challenging to answer. "No equivalent in the Western conceptualization" does not logically require "not believing in the concept," so B should not be right, yet again, the locutions are misleading, which allows Jim's interpretation. But if the West doesn't have it's own "conceptualization," that does not mean it does not believe in the concept which does exist in the East.

Comment: The answer key's description of what answer C says is a direct contradiction of what answer C actually says, however, no matter what misleading (and possibly mistaken, as Noah points out) locutions occur in the text. Only A is correct. B and C are not.

Comment: The text says: "The male/female gender binary dominates Western culture..." which means (according to the author) that "The female/male gender binary is generally considered the norm of contemporary western..." With *not* eliminated, answers A and C make sense. There has to be an error, either it is excerpt C or the suggestion of C is incorrect, the written explanation however, contradicts this.  Nonetheless, on the day of the exam, if a similar mistake arose, the candidate would do well to just choose A. The examiners will take into account the printing error/s.

Comment: @davidshen84. These McGraw Hill GRE books get horrible recommendations on Amazon based on all their typos. There's lots of alternative suggestions there in the reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for us to answer this question definitively; the authors of the question are the only ones capable of doing so. But the following possibilities seem *plausible* to me:

- There is a typo in Answer C and "not" should be removed. (Very likely.)
- There is a typo in Answer C and "male/female binary gender" should be "third gender". (Somewhat likely. "Binary gender" is only used in the passage's first sentence.)
- There is a typo in the explanation. (Unlikely.)
- The usage of "male/female binary" in Answer C is equivalent to the usage of "third" in the explanation. (Very unlikely; binary gender more commonly refers to the concept that there are only two genders and is the same terminology used in the question.)
- Answer C is *actually* asking whether the concept of binary gender is limited to Western culture. (Very unlikely. If this is the implication then both the answer and the explanation are very poorly worded.)
- Answer C is making a distinction between the passage's usage of Western culture and the answer's usage of Western *contemporary* culture. (Very unlikely. This would be a ridiculous semantic trick and is not mentioned in the explanation.)

If I were to answer the question I would have only answered A. You should contact the authors and confirm the made a mistake *or* get a more thorough explanation for why Answer C is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis :) I have tried to contact the author/publisher, no reply so far. I will update this post if I get any any update from them.

Answer (score -2):

There certainly might be an error here, stranger things have happened. But, personally, I am not so sure. Mind you, we *are* talking about the big bad GRE here. Right? GRE is hard-ass, it sure as Taxes ain't no driver's test or GED business, or ACT and SAT combined, for that matter. So, put we our thinking caps on. Oh Dialexis. And muse.

#### *binary*

> **(b1)**
> n.
> That which is constituted of two figures, things, or parts.
>
> ····*It is no wonder then why patriarchy clings so fiercely to dualism. The dualism to which patriarchy subscribes is the gender binary. The gender binary as the false dichotomy of “man” and “woman”, serves as patriarchy’s underlying foundation. It is the assumption that only two genders exist in this world, male and female (despite evidence to the contrary). ... The function of patriarchy’s language is to reinforce the gender binary, yet gender (as a binary) is clearly a falsehood. So how does patriarchy succeed in concealing this dualist fantasy? We have considered the fallacy of the gender binary, its patriarchal purpose, and (briefly) the linguistic and intellectual means through which it is sustained. However, we also need to examine the origin of the gender binary within medical discourse. It might seem obvious that the origin of social gender is social. However, that is not what we are led to believe. We are led to believe that this binary is considered natural, and this “fact” of the culture is the key to keeping patriarchy alive.* / *The gender binary is the artificial division of the world into things that are "masculine" or "for men" and things that are "feminine" or "for women".*
>
> **(b2)**
> adj.
> Having two equally important parts; related to something with two parts. Compounded or consisting of two things or parts; characterized by two (things).
> ·····*A binary statistical distribution has only two categories.* / *This theory of binary composition of all chemical compounds, through the union of electro-positive and electro-negative atoms or molecules, was extended by Berzelius.*

.

#### *gender, n.*

> **(g1)**
> [count noun] Another word for sex.
> ·····*the feminine gender.* / *We all have a gender.* / *Any flowering plant has both genders.*
>
> **(g2)**
> [count noun] Sexual identity, especially in relation to society or culture. The mental analog of sex: one's maleness, femaleness, etc., as seen from their own perspective.
> ·····*Whether it's her personality, her political views, her gender, her sexual orientation, her prior background, or whatever, I don't know (probably differs from person to person). / O'Nan views her gender as an advantage. / I could be wrong, though that's what I heard from a discussion in school from a (female) sociologist (about how society views both genders).*
>
> **(g3)**
> [count noun] The members of one or other sex. Females or males considered as a group. All the members of one sex.
> ·····*differences between the genders are encouraged from an early age* / *expressions used by one gender* / *the entire male gender*
>
> **(g4)**
> [mass noun] The state of being male or female (typically used with reference to social and cultural differences rather than biological ones). A socio-cultural phenomenon that divides people into various categories such as "male" and "female," with each having associated dress, roles, stereotypes, etc.
> ·····*traditional concepts of gender*

Now, regarding the excerpt, in "gender binary", we have a noun (b1), modified by another noun (g_), acting as an adjective, and it can be g1, g2, g3 or g4.

In the "this third gender ... was an established presence in the Vedic culture", we have g2.

Finally, in the "Western conceptualization of gender," we have g4.

On the other hand, in the answer C, "binary gender" is a noun (g_), modified by an adjective (b2). Which g is it?

You have all assumed (Edit: actually, not all) it is g4. I say, it is g1 and g2 simultaneously.

In other words, "binary gender"* has an individual as its target, not the society/population on the whole. When they write "the idea of male/female," they mean "the idea that one person can be g1:male and at the same time be g2:female." Well, most certainly is it **true** that that "is **not** generally considered a **norm** of contemporary Western civilization." Yet.

Ergo: A and C are correct. The answer given is not wrong.

Q.E.D.

*A binary gender is a gender that is neither male nor female. It is a third thing. Nevertheless, it is the [binarity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binarity) that makes it the third.

Comment: Are you saying that there is not even a typo in answer C??  How do you explain that in the face of the first sentence of the paragraph: "The male/female gender binary dominates Western culture"

Comment: Yes. But, of course, none of us can be sure. I was just proving that my hypothesis is as sound as the other one. How do I explain it? Read my post once again.

Comment: Another thing that adds weight to my argument is the fact that, throughout the entire text, it can be felt that they are relating one entire society with its norms—to another society with its own norms. ("Western culture, _yet_", "earliest", "established", "no equivalent"!) The relation is one of nonequivalence. That's what makes the entire text a hot topic. Da difference.

Comment: @Jim: because as Noah et al commented above, a *gender binary* is not the same as a *binary gender*.  Looks like you were applying common sense/normal usage rules to GRE; a foolish error.

Comment: @Jim no that is not a typo.

Comment: Everyone here could use a course in gender studies. I took one 10 years ago in college, and they theory was the same then. It's been greatly expanded since.

Comment: @John The question is straight-forward. In fact there's an explanation in the OP. The GRE isn't about what you seem to think it's about. You don't need a class to understand the questions.

Comment: @user814064 I'm suggesting that a college graduate preparing for a grad school entrance exam (akaGRE), might be operating with a different set of vocabulary than what is common to the average person. And GREs are tailored by subject, so if this is in English or Social Science I may be correct. And I've taken GREs, I have an advanced degree, so I do know what they are about. The discipline that this person is being tested on is not mentioned.

Comment: @John It's a McGraw Hill book that covers the basics and one that most people agree is filled with errors. Read the reviews on Amazon.

Comment: @john There's an obvious consensus. There's even an explanation that proves why the consensus is correct. For B, nothing is suggested. For C, they do not consider the possibility of a 3rd gender. The words "nothing" and "do not" are very clear.

Comment: @user814064 OK Fine. I'm not a baby; I can admit fault. I did *not* read the Answer key. I only read the text and the choices because I assumed a damn reference book to be correct. Of the people who gave an argument that was academic (which I assumed they were looking for), mine was based on a very modern interpretation that I'd expect at the post-graduate level in my defense.. But yeah, no, that's a typo. And I'm not so much of an ass to admit that I was wrong now that you've pointed it out. Frankly, I'm embarrassed that I missed that.